# strange behavior on manipulating DOM with drag and drop

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm using html5 drag and drop to set some values where the div is dropped, but there is some strange behavior that I can't understand it nor to find a solution.

For example if I add elements on position 1,6,11,16 (on diagonal), you'll see that on position 2,3,4 the **div** and **input** gets deleted inside **td**. Why's that?

And for example if I try to clone the element from position 1 to position 2 then **class** gets value "**typeA-1**" for example; of course there is a counter there, but only for id and not for class too, so why the class gets the counter value?

Here is the code on jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/SHLW3/1/

Thanks

```
var counter = 1;
function allowDrop(ev)  {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
}

function clone(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    var original = document.getElementById(data);
    var set = document.getElementById("empty");
    set.firstElementChild.setAttribute("value", data);
    set.setAttribute("id", data+"-"+(counter++));
    set.setAttribute("class", data);
    set.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
    set.setAttribute("ondragstart", "drag(event)");
    set.src = original.src;
    ev.target.appendChild(set);
 }

function trash(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    var set=document.getElementById(data);
    set.setAttribute("id", "empty");
    set.setAttribute("class", "empty");
    set.firstElementChild.setAttribute("value", "empty");
    set.removeAttribute("draggable");
    set.removeAttribute("ondragstart");
}
```

Comment: Your problem stems from having multiple elements with the same id. You have a bunch of elements with the id `empty`, so `var set = document.getElementById("empty");` is not well-defined.

Comment: The class also updates to the id, because ondrag you set the Text data to the id, and then when you clone an element you set the class to that data section.

Comment: well yea, but when I drop seems to get that specific id and change it accordingly. I don't understand why is deleting other elements with the same ID. I could put different IDs but then how do I get them and change the values? The main thing that I need is to change the input value accordingly with the div class so I can submit it and add it in database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the approach I used is totally wrong so I used a new one. Instead of setting the attributes I actually cloned the base 'div' with 'cloneNode(true)' and then got the cloned element parent and set the input value.

```
function clone(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    var original = document.getElementById(data);
    var clone = original.cloneNode(true);
    var copyimg = original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
    copyimg.setAttribute("id", data+'-'+counter++);
    ev.target.appendChild(copyimg);
    var set = copyimg.parentNode;
    set.firstElementChild.setAttribute("value", data.split('-')[0]);
 }
```